# Find caluclation to equal this value?

Tags: problem-solving

How can I find the calculation needed to reach the given value?
This is related to programming but I don't see how I can do this myself.

```
A = 1535683044
B = 1583000036
C = 155934150
```

What equation could be used with `A` and `B` to result in `C`?

**Edit:**
Is this even possible?

Comment: Try $C=\frac{A+B}{2}$. Pretty close.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that works!

Comment: @AndréNicolas im trying this against all the other values, this seems to be the relation. mind making your comment an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Not quite. When we do the operation, at the end we get $170$ not $150$. Maybe there is a typo in one of your numbers. But at least we get an excellent approximation.

Comment: OK, will do that, to get it off the unanswered list.

Comment: $C$ has a digit less than $A$ and $B$, so it cannot be the arithmetic mean of $A$ and $B$, not even a "good" approximation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find that $C$ is very close to $\frac{A+B}{20}$.

**Remark:** Perhaps it is intended that $C$ be *exactly* $\frac{A+B}{20}$, or $\frac{A+B}{2}$. If so, there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: OK, this works.

Comment: is there also a way I can use C to find A and B?

Comment: We cannot find $A$ and $B$ if all we know is $C$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see, thank you for the help.